# Apply $R_{n}$ to each of the standard basis vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

Recently, I'm reading a book named *3D Game Programming With DirectX 11*, and there is a 
linear transformation I cannot figure it out (3.1.4 Rotation in Chapter 3).

It describe rotating a vector **v** about an axis **n** by angle $\theta$.

[image]

And the book gives me the following rotation furmula:

$$
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
R_{n}(v)&=proj_{n}(v)+R_{n}(v_{\perp})\\
&=(n \cdot v)n+cos\theta v_{\perp}+sin\theta(n\times v)\\
&=(n \cdot v)n+cos(v-(n \cdot v)n)+sin\theta (n \times v)\\
&=cos\theta v+(1-cos\theta )(n \cdot v)n+sin\theta (n \times v)
\end{split}\end{equation}
$$

Now we let $c = cos\theta$ and $s=sin\theta$, and **apply $R_{n}$to each of the standard 
basis vectors, and then place the resulting vectors into the rows of a matrix.the final
result is:**

$$
R_{n}=
\begin{bmatrix}
c+(1-c)x^2 & (1-c)xy+sz & (1-c)xz-sy\\
(1-c)xy-sz & c+(1-c)y^2 & (1-c)yz+sx\\
(1-c)xz+sy & (1-c)yz-sx & c+(1-c)z^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I cannot figure it out ,what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you're mainly concerned with the part you put in bold text.

> *apply $R_n$ to each of the standard basis vectors, and then place the resulting vectors into the rows of a matrix*

In terms of the standard basis vectors $e_i$, $e_iR_n$ is the $i$th row that you inserted into $R_n$, and this simply represents the coordinates of the standard basis vector $e_i$ after rotation.

The thing to keep in mind is that after you've determined how to map the basis vectors, the images of *all* remaining vectors are completely determined already. That's why building a matrix using the standard basis vectors results in a matrix that works for the rest of the vectors.

---

Conceptually, the rotation looks a lot simpler if you take $n$ and normalize it to $u$, and use it as the first basis element. Then you can cook up an orthonormal basis $u,a,b$ and the matrix to rotate around $n$ looks like this:

$$
R'=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\cos(\theta)&\sin(\theta)\\0&-\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}
$$

where you are multiplying with row vectors on the left.

The problem is that this isn't the transformation to the *standard basis*, it's with respect to our odd basis $\{u,a,b\}$. The steps they took above build the similar matrix in terms of the standard basis, making it look more complicated. These two matrices are related by some nonsingular matrix $X$ such that $XR'X^{-1}=R_n$.